# Change time format in a file

Tags: linux, sed, posix, sar

I have output of a sar commands and the time is not POSIX:

```
Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 (test.server.com)  2015-08-01  _x86_64_    (32 CPU)

12:00:01 AM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all      0.01      0.00      0.07      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     99.93
12:10:01 AM       0      0.01      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     99.97
[…]
```

I am trying to figure out how to figure out how to replace the time from 12:00:01 AM into posix 00:00:01 on lines that starts with time.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd do it this way:

- parse the time into epoch format.
- print the epoch time in the desired output format.

E.g. like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my ( $time_str ) = m/^([\d\:]+ [AP]M)/;
   print $time_str, "=>",;
   my $newtime = Time::Piece -> strptime ( $time_str, "%I:%M:%S %p" );
   print $newtime->strftime("%H:%M:%S"),"\n";
}

__DATA__
12:00:01 AM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all      0.01      0.00      0.07      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     99.93
12:10:01 AM       0      0.01      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     99.97
```

Which with your script would therefore be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

while (<>) {
    if ( my ($time_str) = m/^([\d\:]+ [AP]M)/ ) {
        my $new_time_str = Time::Piece->strptime( $time_str, "%I:%M:%S %p" )
            ->strftime("%H:%M:%S");
        s/$time_str/$new_time_str/;
    }
    print;
}
```

That'll work 'inline' - `<>` is perl magic to allow you to:

- `./myscript.pl some_file`
- `some_command | ./myscript.pl`

Can probably one-linerify this as:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe 's/^([\d\:]+ [AP]M)/Time::Piece->strptime( $1, q{%I:%M:%S %p} )->strftime(q{%H:%M:%S})/e;'
```

Comment: Many thanks !! It did the trick.
The one-liner complains about the library Time::Piece not loaded but the second script perfectly works.

Comment: Amended the one liner to load the module correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in future files you can get the output in 24 hour format by
clearing your locale, which is presumably en_US or similar, which is why
you are getting AM/PM.  Eg:

```
$ LANG=C sar -u 2 5
13:32:30        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
```

whereas

```
$ LANG=en_US sar -u 2 5
01:32:02 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
```

Comment: I know I got this from a customer :/ and the saXX files are not anymore available